# Using filter_by after join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using `filter_by` after a join results in an error because SQLAlchemy tries to find that column in the joined table instead of the original one.

Is there a way around this? Like unjoining, after filtering on something from the other table.

For instance, say I am filtering rows from table A because of relationship with a certain set of rows in table B. After that I want to filter on some table A fields, but when using filter_by it gives an error.

Comment: Please show us your code and errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter). It's like `filter_by`, but you explicitly use column expressions instead of keyword arguments. This lets you specify the table whose column you want:

```
joined_query.filter(A.field == something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter_by:

```
join_query.filter_by(Table.column1='value')
```

Using filter:

```
join_query.filter(Table.column1 == 'value')
```